# Error When Trying to Compile in Eclipse (MacOSX)

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++

I am learning Eclipse and C++ and am working on an extremely simple program. I can't build the program now. I just recently installed HomeBrew so I don't know if that has something to do with it. Here is my code (it's from a simple tutorial I'm working off of so I know the code works because I've seen it work on the tutorial):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Ask the user to input a word while the word length < 5
    string word = "";

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a word that has at least 5 characters: " << endl;
        cin >> word;
    }while(word.size() < 5);

    // Ask the user to input a character
    char searchCh = '0';

    cout << "Enter a character and the program will tell" <<
        " you how many times it appears in the word " << word << "." << endl;
    cin >> searchCh;

    int counter = 0;

    // Iterate over the word
    for(int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
    {
        // Get a character
        char ch = word.at(i);

        // If the character matches the character we're looking for
        if(searchCh == ch)
        {
            // Increment a counter
            counter++;
        }
    }
    // Output the number of times the character was found in the word.
    cout << "The number of " << searchCh << "'s in the word " << word << " is " << counter << "\n";

    return 0;       
}
```

The error I get when build is this:

```
g++  -o "Program 5"  ./Program5.o   
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Program 5] Error 1
```

I've seen several other similar question on here about going to 'Project' and 'Properties' but I don't know what settings exactly are supposed to be updated to get this working. Also, some of the other answers mentioned that a main() function is needed to fix this issue, but I obviously have one in this code. It was working fine last week when I was using Eclipse on other small projects so I'm not sure what changed.

For further information:
When I first the set the project up, it is set as an 'Empty Project' project type with 'MacOSX GCC' as the toolchain. I then created a source file (with the .cpp extension) within the project, wrote the code, and then that's where I'm at.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Explaining downvotes is always good...

Comment: Your code doesn't have a return statement. Is this just in the post or in the code too?

Comment: @Avery, I've just added it to the code here. I had forgotten it but am still getting the same error regardless.

Comment: Ok. Does the compilation work outside of eclipse?

Comment: Well I don't know exactly how to check that. I'm a beginner and am trying to learn how to get this all set up straight. If you're referring to the code, it should work as I've taken it straight from a tutorial and have watched that code work in the video. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: What is the filename of your code?

Comment: Program5.cpp is the file name.

Comment: Try deleting the current project, creating a new one, and importing the existing files. Make sure that you make a C++ project.

Comment: Project looks ok for me. Looks like you have path problem in linker. Could you write sample hello world and try to compile and link it in command line prompt using exactly this version of CLang.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any reason why you're using Eclipse instead of Xcode? I mean, Xcode is supposed to work a lot better in general. I'm not trying to start a new discussion, but as a Mac user I don't see why you'd want to use Eclipse for learning C++.

Comment: Source is definitely buildable, so I suppose trouble is in old .o file. Try to delete `Program5.o` or just select 'Clean project', then 'Build project'. If you use default settings, Eclipse will cleanup intermediate files for you.

Comment: @Avery, that worked. Do you have any idea why that would happen (I'm thinking more for future people who have a similar problem)? I set up the initial C++ project the same way as far as I can remember and have done it several times now so I'm not sure why that would've broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting up your project. Sometimes installing buildchains can confuse eclipse and make it use the wrong libraries - especially if it is expecting another version.

What I think happened here is that eclipse confused was using a buildpath that did not contain C++ files (due to an upgrade moving them?) but instead contained C files, which don't link with C++ under normal circumstances.

As also mentioned by [another commenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224488/error-when-trying-to-compile-in-eclipse-macosx#comment39379626_25224488), this could also be the result of an initial failed build not being cleaned up for some reason.

Sometimes with eclipse, the solution is the same as with Windows: Restart it, redo whatever went wrong again.